# Connecting for file in qt

Tags: qt, file, connect

I am trying to use qt to write an application that connects back to my computer to retrieve files. Example: My friend would open up the app and when it opens, it connects to my computer and takes off of it the file it needs then disconnects. How would I do that and or what tools would I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Qt for this. You need and FTP server and client.

In lieu of that, if you really want to learn something, I would run an FTP server on your computer and use Qt to write an FTP transfer mechanism. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qftp.html

In lieu of that, if you want to do something from the ground up in Qt, you can poke around starting here. http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/qtdocs/qtcpserver.html.

Doing this in Qt will have the same principles as doing it in any other framework or language. I recommend that before you do this you get a firm grounding in TCP/IP and the OSI model.

Comment: I am considering making the application opensource. How would I prevent people from seeing the address of the ftp server on my computer and then spamming my computer?

Comment: @ a sandwhich This really should be another question entirely, but why would you hard-code an FTP address in your code? Every time the server changes for some reason, you'll need to re-compile and redistribute. This should be done with a config file. Secondly, if you're running a public server, you run the risk of getting unwanted traffic. Period. Make strong passwords and segregate your network from the server. Also run your server in a software sandbox. Again, you do not need Qt for this. Use a FTP server/client. Filezilla is a good client. server: cerberus for windows, vsftpd for unix.